# Apps Script debugger doesn't breakpoints don't work with forms, right?

Tags: forms, debugging, google-apps-script

From what I can tell the Apps Script debugger is not useful for me. Am I wrong somewhere?

Scenario:

- Sidebar gets installed on the spreadsheet. Part of its generates a form for the user to enter data
- User enters values into the sidebar on my form, then clicks OK
- Those values are sent to a function in the script

Which means that the debugger is useless in this situation, correct? Because it only works by calling a function. Since the function relies on input from the form, it fails.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to set a breakpoint such that after execution has been transferred from my sidebar that it stops, you know, where I set the breakpoint?

Comment: The debugger works for server side code.  You have to learn how to use Chrome Developer tools to debug clientside.  I mostly just use the console.

Comment: To clarify, I'm assuming you mean an HTML form and not Google forms. Also, since its a function on server side, you could first mimic the use of said function by creating another `test` function and passing dummy variables & invoking the original function instead. Would help if you could share the script (or a redacted version of it so we could explore further ways for you to debug).

Comment: You can implement logs with `Logger.log` at strategic positions in your code - this will help you debugging.

Comment: The code editor debug breakpoints only stop the code if you start running the code from inside the code editor.  So, for what you are asking, "yes" the debugger is useless for that situation.  You could simulate a value being passed in from the client by temporarily hard coding the value in the function for testing.  I often write out logs to a spreadsheet for debugging, but you need to add a custom solution for that.

Comment: To add to @ziganotschka logger.log will not show up in your Apps Script Execution tab, you have to look at your browser's console. Every browser has a console that you can open. This website has instructions on how to: https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/